UseState hook is not working for me. Can someone please help me understand the error I'm getting after I use UseState?
Ok so I'm gonna keep this simple. I'm new to React, and I am having a very hard time with hooks. This is the error: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not a function or its return value is not iterable
Here is my code for my render and ReactDom and everything
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 import './index.css';
 import Test from './test';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Test />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

And here is my code for the component Test.
import useState from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    console.log(setMessage("GOODBYE"));
    return (
        <div>HEY</div>
    );
}
export default Test;

Someone please help me I am really confused.

What connect button are you referring to? What is the error? Please [edit] to include clearer and more specific details, and the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace(s). Take the full [tour] and see Help/How to Ask for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Note also that trying to do imperative DOM manipulation in React will almost certainly not work the way you want it to. And your "component" isn't actually a component? Your code doesn't really make a lot of sense as written, you would do better working through some basic tutorials first.

Creating a websocket doesn’t guarantee that the client side has approved/accepted and that you’re all ready to go!
So where's your error checking?
try{

 const socket= new WebSocket(url);

} catch(e){
    
 alert(e); // Maybe e.reason ???

}

Or to use your format...
socket.onerror = function(e) {alert(e);};

ie: My custom browser blocks all websockets unless whitelisted domain and/or membership account exists.
Error checking would of course also (hopefully) inform of any other issues that may arise.
WebSockets bible for reference...
https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org//#concept-websocket-close-fail
